# How do I assign the Analytics cloud builder permission set license to a user?

Tags: permissions, permission-sets, einstein-analytics, licenses, einstein

I've been trying to use Einstein Analytics. I've enabled analytics but I'm still not getting the analytics studio app in the app menu. I am not able to assign the Analytics cloud builder license to anything. It says that: 'All Analytics Cloud Builder permission set licenses are in use. For more licenses, contact your salesforce.com representative.'

I've not used any license at all. Here are some screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developer.salesforce.com/promotions/orgs/wave-de

Got it. You can't have permissions for einstein analytics on a regular org. You need to create a new einstein-enabled org for this using the link above.